# How to get terraform to use the ~/.kube/config file for auth to k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I've spun up a simple k8s cluster in my lab. In the process of doing so, I generated a kubeconfig located at `~/.kube/config`. I can confirm that the config is good using kubectl. I can I am attempting to configure resources on this cluster using terraform, and looking at the documentation [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/guides/getting-started) it appears that I can just reference the kubeconfig in the provider to handle authentication to the cluster, which I did.

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/config"
}
```

Unfortunately, however, that doesn't seem to work. The output from the terraform apply command seems to indicate that it's trying to hit the cluster via localhost:80 rather than the endpoint defined in the config file. I saw some mention online of needing to specify `config_context` as well, but unfortunately, that resulted in the same error as seen here:

```
│ Error: Post "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
│
│   with kubernetes_namespace.test,
│   on main.tf line 35, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test":
│   35: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test" {
```

I feel like I must be missing something here, but can't for the life of me figure out what it could possibly be. I would assume that the kubeconfig file should be sufficient for the auth. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you have environment variables KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST and KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT set; terraform will think that it is running within a cluster. Try unset them if they do exist.

Comment: Hi conplexed welcome to SO. Please be aware that `~/` is a shell construct, and might not be expanded by terraform. Also, since `$HOME/.kube/config` is the default path consulted by kubectl and any reasonable kubernetes client API, you may have more success by just not specifying `config_path` in your file

Comment: @conplexed which K8s provider version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for all of the responses, everyone. Let me run through them all.

First, I confirmed that unfortunately there are no env vars set named KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST/PORT. That would have just been too easy. Second, I believe I had tried ommiting the `config_path` before as well, but I tried it just in case and that still results in the same error. Lastly, the version of k8s provider I am using is 2.4.1 with Terraform 1.0.5.

Comment: Oh, I also tried `$HOME/.kube/config` as well. No luck :(

Comment: @conplexed did you ever manage to find a fix for this?

Comment: Sorry, @ElliotBlackburn, I did not get this figured out and ended up pivoting away from Terraform for this task.